# Dynamic change bash prompt according to path

Tags: command-prompt, prompt, bash, ps1

I would like to know if it is possible to change the PS1 according to the current path or pwd value?

For example:

```
cd /home/user/directory1
PS1=[\e[1;32m\u\e[m@\e[1;34m\h\e[m \e[1;33m\W\e[m]
```

But if i'm in an another directory :

```
cd /home/user/thisdirectory
PS1=[\w]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
[user1@myhost ~]myfunc() { DIR=`pwd`;if [ "$DIR" = "/home/user1" ]; then  export PS1="[\e[1;32m\u\e[m@\e[1;34m\h\e[m \e[1;33m\W\e[m]" ;else export PS1="[\w]";fi; }
[user1@myhost ~]PROMPT_COMMAND="myfunc"
[user1@myhost ~]cd /tmp
[/tmp]cd
[user1@myhost ~]cd /etc
[/etc]cd
[user1@myhost ~]
```

When I am changing the directory the prompt is getting changed.

Comment: Vey nice!  Clever to assign a func to the PROMPT_COMMAND

Answer (score 7):

The `PROMPT_COMMAND` bash variable is what you're looking for:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND
       If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing
       each primary prompt.
```