# How to show a custom variable just like $HOME in command PROMPT in terminal

Tags: unix, terminal, command, command-prompt

I am trying to change my command prompt to show the working directory
But my working directory path gets very long.

Lets say I have a variable `MY_WORK_DIRECTORY` point to a large path `/Users/foo/work/project/../`

Now in the prompt i can say `PROMPT='%~%# '`

so that give a relative path like `~/work/project/app` whenever i am in app

how can i set a prompt in which i could see `MY_WORK_DIRECTORY/app`  whenever i am in my work directory

Comment: Is this a request for `bash`?

Comment: Probable duplicate: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731727/dynamic-change-bash-prompt-according-to-path